# Sort the list of figures by caption

Tags: table-of-contents, sorting

I would like to sort the list of figures by caption alphabetically (instead of the order of appearance).

Something like

```
List of figures

4 Aaaa      3
1 Bbbbb     1
8 Ddd dd    10
```

Is there a way?

Comment: The makeindex package might help.  Normally LOF entries are stored as a file, as opposed to labels which are stored as global macros `\csname r@labelname\endcsname`.  The aux file shows what information is available to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `latex3` implementation, using `\tex_strcmp:D` to compare strings.

- Here `\tex_strcmp:D` is the latex3 alias taken from primitive `\pdfstrcmp` in pdftex or `\strcmp` in xetex. It takes two arguments, and expands to 1 if arg1 > arg2, to 0 if arg1 == arg2, and to -1 if otherwise.
- 18 May 2020 update: It is now compatible with both `tocbibind` (which redefines `\listoffigures`) and `hyperref` (which redefines `\contentsline`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

% a seq of clist "<sort key>,<orig contents line>"
\seq_new:N \g_lof_seq

% backup
\cs_set_eq:NN \contentsline_orig \contentsline
\cs_set_eq:NN \numberline_orig   \numberline


% patch \@starttoc to insert two hooks
\xpatchcmd \@starttoc
  { \begingroup }
  {
    \begingroup
    \tl_if_eq:nnT {#1} {lof}
      { \hook_before_starttoc: }
  }
  {}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd \@starttoc
  { \endgroup }
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnT {#1} {lof}
      { \hook_after_starttoc: }
    \endgroup
  }
  {}{\fail}


% hook inserted at the beginning of \@starttoc
\cs_new:Nn \hook_before_starttoc:
  {
    \seq_clear:N \g_lof_seq

    \cs_set_eq:NN \contentsline \contentsline_new
    \cs_set_eq:NN \numberline   \numberline_new
  }


% hook inserted at the end of \@starttoc
\cs_new:Nn \hook_after_starttoc:
  {
    % for i in seq, sort by the top element of i
    \seq_sort:Nn \g_lof_seq
      {
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {##2}
        \clist_get:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
        \clist_get:NN \l_tmpb_clist \l_tmpb_tl

        \int_compare:nNnTF
          % \tex_strcmp:D is the primitive \pdfstrcmp in pdftex 
          % or \strcmp in xetex
          { \exp_args:NVV \tex_strcmp:D \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl } = 1
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
          { \sort_return_same: }
      }

    % restore
    \cs_set_eq:NN \contentsline \contentsline_orig
    \cs_set_eq:NN \numberline   \numberline_orig

    % output
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lof_seq
      {
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
        \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2}
      }
  }


% variant definition of \contentsline
% for every <contents line>, store clist of "<title>,<orig contents line>" in \g_lof_seq
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {
    % eg, \contentsline{figure}{\numberline{3}{\ignorespaces Aaa}}{2}{figure.3}%
    \cs_new:Npn \contentsline_new #1#2#3#4
      {
        % eg, #2 == \numberline{3}{\ignorespaces Aaa}
        #2

        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 
          { \contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} } % different here

        \seq_gput_right:NV \g_lof_seq \l_tmpa_clist
      }
  }
  {
    % eg, \contentsline{figure}{\numberline{3}{\ignorespaces Aaa}}{2}%
    \cs_new:Npn \contentsline_new #1#2#3
      {
        % eg, #2 == \numberline{3}{\ignorespaces Aaa}
        #2

        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 
          { \contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3} } % different here

        \seq_gput_right:NV \g_lof_seq \l_tmpa_clist
      }
  }

% variant definition of \numberline, store title part in \l_tmpa_tl
\cs_new:Npn \numberline_new #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures (sorted by title)}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\begin{figure} content \caption{Ddd} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} content \caption{Bbb} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} content \caption{Aaa} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} content \caption{Ccc} \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's not working with the package tocbibind but I'll try to figure out why

Comment: With tobibind I get no errors but the content is not ordered anymore. With hyperref I get some additional text (figure.0, figure.1) before the list of figures

Comment: @Matteo Answer is updated, now it is compatible with both `tocbibind` and `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks again. Works perfectly